# Android Logcat with USB device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

In my development with Andriod Studio with an native library I can see now the log writing inside the logcat window. But because it is not possible to connect the tablet with USB to Android Studio and also use a USB hdd device, I have to run the app on the tablet to see the logs.
But how I can acces this logs if the app runs on the tablet with an connected hdd and not the tablet connected with USB to Android Studio?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/wifi-adb

Answer (score 1):

Michael's comment should be an Answer. You can connect to ADB through network.

Connect it through USB first, enable adb networking on the device by doing
`adb tcpip 5555`, then you can disconnect USB and connect through network by doing `adb connect 192.168.ip_of_device`